# What Events does the Setting Charm fires?

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

Does a page is getting an event when the Setting Charm is closed?

Thanks
EitanB

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no event when the pane is closed - depending on your particular implementation, you can either rely on [CommandRequested](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.applicationsettings.settingspane.commandsrequested) - triggered **when a specific item was selected**, or on your independent handler that is in your Popup (that might show specific setting options).

Comment: Hi, 
Thanks for your answer.
I am familiar with CommandRequest. I am trying to get an event in the page after/when the user leaves the Settings Charm.
EitanB

Comment: There is no specific event, as I said. You need to detect something outside the shell, like the closing of a secondary popup itself.

Answer (score 1):

```
Windows.UI.ApplicationSettings.SettingsPane.GetForCurrentView().CommandsRequested
```